# SQL Group By date field and SUM IF dates match

Tags: sql, group-by, duckdb

I have a bunch of date fields

```
Started     Completed  Status
----------  ---------- ----------
2000-01-30  2000-01-31 2000-01-31
2000-01-30  2000-02-01 2000-02-01
```

I need the counts of `Started` and `Completed` by `Status` month:

```
Started Completed  Status
------- ---------  ------
2       1          Jan-2000
.       1          Feb-2000
```

I've gotten to something like

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', Status) AS Status,
       SUM(IF(DATE_TRUNC('month', Started) = DATE_TRUNC('month', Status), 1, 0)) AS Started,
       SUM(IF(DATE_TRUNC('month', Completed) = DATE_TRUNC('month', Status), 1, 0)) AS Completed
FROM table
GROUP BY Status
```

This gives me

```
Started Completed  Status
------- ---------  ------
1       1          Jan-2000
.       1          Feb-2000
```

I need `Started` to be **2** in January

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. But  a date has a year _field_. a month _field_ and a day _field_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the list of all status with your table then apply your conditions to get counts of Started and Completed by Status month :

```
SELECT S_Status,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('month', Started) = S_Status THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Started,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('month', Completed) = S_Status THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed
FROM mytable t
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC('month', Status) as S_Status
  FROM mytable
) AS s ON DATE_TRUNC('month', Started) = S_Status
       OR DATE_TRUNC('month', Completed) = S_Status
GROUP BY S_Status;
```

Results :

```
S_Status    Started Completed
2000-01     2       1
2000-02     0       1
```

Since I don't have duckdb I have tested it using postgresql [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qbXnCvEf)